# Rates of change question?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> A boat is observed from top of a $100\ \text m$ high cliff. The boat is
>   travelling towards the cliff at a speed of $50\ \text{m/min}$. How fast is angle
>   of depression changing when angle of depression is $15^\circ$. Give
>   your answer to the nearest degree.

I differentiated $\theta$ with respect to time and got $\dfrac{-5000}{x^2 + 100^2}$
and substituted $x=\dfrac{100}{\tan15^\circ}$, but got the wrong answer.

Can someone please show me the correct steps?

Comment: Is the answer 0.033 degrees/min?

Comment: The answer is 2 degrees/min , but I got 0.033 for some reason.

Comment: Well, that's a pretty big difference...

Answer (score 2):

It looks as if you basically did it a correct way. But the answer you get out of the calculation is in **radians** per minute. Convert to degrees.